# difference between FullSimplify and Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics

I have a problem to dinstinguish the following two mathematica codes, the only difference is the first use FullSimplify and the second is Simplify. but the results are totally different. what is wrong, is it a bug or not ? I really cannot figure it out

first codes are

```
f = WaveletPsi[MorletWavelet[], x]; 
g = FourierTransform[f, x, y, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}] // FullSimplify; 
Plot[g, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

the output figure is

[image]

the second codes are

```
f = WaveletPsi[MorletWavelet[], x]; 
g = FourierTransform[f, x, y, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}] // Simplify; 
Plot[g, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

the output figure is
[image]

Why is there so big difference of the output figures?  I just modify the first codes from FullSimplify to Simplify !

anyone understand it ? Is it bug or not ?

I,due to low reputation, cannot post the formula about difference between the output formula with FullSimplify and Simplify: Ok, now I　can post the formula:
[image]

anyone understand it ? Thanks.

thank you very mcuh, everyone, to give the advice. by the way, how can I acknowledge your contributions ?

thanks to the firends below, I have found the hints for this problem. this is due to the floating point error in numerical calculation inlcuding substractive cancellation, loss of significance, etc. In In usual cases, the default precision may deal with these erros well, however, for diverging term, the default precision may not handle it. so increasing precision may solve it. or by changing algrithom, like what Submit has done, may also handle it without changing precision. 
well, thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`?

Comment: sorry, I try to post the figures of the outputs of Simplify and Fullsimplify, but I cannot due to low reputation. I think it may be a bug of mathematica.

Comment: I can't run your code at the moment (I'm on a tablet), but I suspect that FullSimplify may be generating a simpler expression that happens to be less sensitive to numerical precision problems. Perhaps you could try adding the option `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` to the Plot after Simplify, and see if anything changes.

Comment: Yes, it's ol' "subtractive cancellation" all over again. Notice that in the result of `Simplify[]`, you have a result composed of adding and subtracting a bunch of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ terms, which get big pretty quick, to get a result that is not very big. It's a recipe for screw-ups. Stick with `FullSimplify[]`.

Comment: Thanks, MarcoB, I tried your advised option, the output figure changes, but it is still different from that with FullSimplify. (Sorry that  I cannot post the figure due to restriction of my reputation.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, J. M. , I think you are correct. You are really nice.

Comment: You can set a higher WorkingPrecision, say 30, and then the plots will look the same.  This shows that the formulas are indeed equivalent, so you can confidently use the FullSimplify output.

Comment: yes, it is, when I set WorkingPrecision to 60, tht figures are the same, thank you very much, Szabolcs! you are vert smart!

Comment: Note: Neither `Simplify` nor `FullSimplify` guarantees to minimize loss of precision.  They're symbolic simplifiers, not numerical ones.

Comment: thank you for warm discussion, everyone, Submit, Szabolc, Michael E2, J. M., MaccoB, How can I aknowledge your contributions ?

Comment: after I serach some refs, I find taht this is due to floating-point error, such as subtractive cancllation, loss of significance. when the term is diverging, the error will become apparent in the numerical calculation. increasing precision or changing algrithom may solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happens if there is a diverging term appears in the middle. For your case If we consider

> FourierTransform[f, x, y, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}] = [Pi]^(1/4)/ Sqrt@2  (c1 + c2 + c3 + c4)

```
c1 = Cosh[1/2 \[Pi]^2 (-2 y + Sqrt[2/Log[2]])^2]
c2 = Cosh[1/2 \[Pi]^2 (2 y + Sqrt[2/Log[2]])^2]
c3 = -Sinh[1/2 \[Pi]^2 (-2 y + Sqrt[2/Log[2]])^2]
c4 = -Sinh[1/2 \[Pi]^2 (2 y + Sqrt[2/Log[2]])^2]
```

Individually these functions are diverging

```
Plot[Evaluate@{c1, c2, c3, c4}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLegends -> {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"}]
```

[image]

But their combination might have aslower divergence

```
Plot[Evaluate@{c1 + c3, c2 + c4}, {y, -.5, .5}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {"c1+c3", "c2+c4"}]
```

[image]

When you are using `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` they follow certain algorithm to handle these divergences which give you different results. It sometimes may depend on how you write your expression as well. For example

```
Plot[(c1 + c2 + c3 + c4), {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "(c1+c2+c3+c4)"]
Plot[(c1 + c3 + c2 + c4), {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "(c1+c3+c2+c4)"]
Plot[(c1 + c3) + (c2 + c4), {y, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "(c1+c3)+(c2+c4)"]
```

[image]

Fortunately I don't know any further details, so I can stop here.

Comment: thanks a lot, Sumit, you are quite right, due to these diverging terms, the working precision will influence the results of Mathematica.significantly. at first, i do not know this point, by default working precision, expression c1+c2+c3+c4 give a wrong result, but thanks to advice of Szabolc, when i set WorkingPrecision ->60 in the Plot[], the expression c1+c2+c3+c4 can give the right figure like (c1+c3)+(c2+c4)